# Duplicates in ArrayList using For loop (JAVA)

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to generate any number of families using For Loop, those families are saved in ArrayList. But when I choose for example generate 1 family, I get two identical families in the ArrayList, although I have a method for saving only unique fammilies.

```
//Code for generating families

public static void firstOption(int count) {
    ArrayList<String> womanNames = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Irina"));
    ArrayList<String> manNames = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"));
    ArrayList<String> surnames = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Surname1", "Surname2", "Surname3", "Surname4"));
    ArrayList<Integer> iq = new ArrayList<>(List.of(80, 100, 120, 90));

    long minDay = LocalDate.of(1970, 1, 1).toEpochDay();
    long maxDay = LocalDate.of(2015, 12, 31).toEpochDay();
    long randomDay = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(minDay, maxDay);
    LocalDate randomDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(randomDay).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int indexManName = (int) (Math.random() * manNames.size());
        int indexWomanName = (int) (Math.random() * manNames.size());
        int indexSurname = (int) (Math.random() * surnames.size());
        int indexIq = (int) (Math.random() * iq.size());
        Man father = new Man(manNames.get(indexManName), surnames.get(indexSurname), randomDate.format(formatter), iq.get(indexIq));
        Woman mother = new Woman(womanNames.get(indexWomanName), father.getSurname(), randomDate.format(formatter), iq.get(indexIq));
        familyController.createNewFamily(father, mother);
    }
}

//This is the code for creating and saving new Family to ArrayList

public Family saveFamily(Family family) {
    int index = this.familyList.indexOf(family);
    if (this.familyList.contains(family)) {
        this.familyList.set(index, family);
    } else {
        this.familyList.add(family);
    }

    return family;
}

public Family createNewFamily(Human mother, Human father) {
    return familyDao.saveFamily(new Family(mother, father));
}

//Override family equals
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;

    if (!(obj instanceof Family myFamily))
      return false;

    return (mother.hashCode() == myFamily.getMother().hashCode());
}
```

Comment: `if (this.familyList.contains(family))` Does `Family` override `equals()` method? If not you'll never get this method to work correctly. Also, you might want to read about [sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Comment: Thanks, I know about sets, but I need Arraylist in this case.@Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof Family myFamily))
      return false;
    return (mother.hashCode() == myFamily.getMother().hashCode());
  }

Comment: That `equals()` method is definitely broken. You may find how `equals()` and `hashCode()` work on the internet. Also you can generate these methods, modern IDEs such as IDEA or Eclipse have this function. And don't forget to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` for your other classes (Man, Woman, etc.) as well.